# Sweden work permit

Tags: sweden, work-permit

I came to Sweden on July 2017 with work permit visa upto Dec2021, but due to project criticality company wants to extend my visa and applied (on nov 2021 last week ) for extension upto may2022 and still the decision pending for extension with migrationsverket.

In the mean time I have got an offer from another company and they started my visa process from June 2022. I have to go back to my country and bring my family.

So my question is I have two applications in my name with 2 different employers with different dates, now migrationsverket will approve my visa or not? If they approve which visa they will do? I don't want to lose the job I got in Sweden. A little information would help me to understand and find solution for my case.

Comment: Have you spoken to your existing employer about withdrawing the extension application? What did your proposed new employer say about the pending application?

Comment: Something is not right with the dates- your company applied 21 Nov 2021 and you are asking now on 23 March 2022. Did you get a work permit for four years and not 2+2? You next employer wants you to start working on June 2022?  Does your current employer know about your plans? Anyway, the bottom line is that if your occupation is the same in both companies than one application is enough, if you are changing roles than only the new company needs to apply. Read more on [migrationsverket](https://www.migrationsverket.se/English/Private-individuals/Working-in-Sweden/Employed/Changing-jobs.html)